# Jquery not returning href text value correctly

Tags: jquery

I have the following code below and i trying to get the value of the text on which the user has moused over .. currently its returning nothing.

here is my code below and fiddle here [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/e11zpt5r/9/) (line number 263 to 269

```
var LinkVal = $(this).closest('div.previewCard-b').find('.previewCardPageLink').text();
console.log(" LinkVal  " + LinkVal);
console.log(" sometext " +$(this).parent().find('.previewCardPageLink').text());                                
var assembledInfo = LinkVal + ' | Ohm';
alert("assembledInfo " +assembledInfo)
```

Comment: When adding live demo please add **minimal** code that is necessary to reproduce the issue

Comment: What about using `$that` rather than `this`?

Comment: err, almost 400 isn't minimal enough for me to delve into your code and give you an exact answer, but if you want an href string, since its an attribute, you get it with attr('href') and **not** text()

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Just tried "that" didnt return anything

Comment: @user244394 `this` is the window object in that scope, I really doubt that is what you want to use. You are not correctly using your selectors then, or rather you are trying to select an item that isn't there when attempting to look for it.

Comment: 363 lines of javascript + html structure to understand the problem. Drill down your problem by writing simple code.

Comment: Agree to what JSelser said. Use attr('href') to get the url in href. Do console.log to log the elements you are using to get the link value.

Comment: @CheezyCode I am not lookign to get the url value. i need the text value ie <a href="#"> I need this val</a>

Comment: Again, `this` is the **`window`** in the scope of the anonymous function in `setTimeout`, clearly it does not have a parent and is not the item you want to look for.

Comment: use .html() for it then.

Comment: I tried doing this $('div.previewCard-b').find('.previewCardPageLink').text(); which returns all the text values between all the links..  i just need the text name for the link  mouse overed on

Comment: @user244394 Why not just add an event handler for the links and give `$(this).text()`? look like you would apply it to the classes `med-link` and `black-link`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek is this what you meant , I changed as per ur suggestion  here is the update http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/e11zpt5r/10/   it didnt work $(this).text()

Comment: @user244394 [This is what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/e11zpt5r/11/). Hover over the link and their text will be printed to the console. Here is one with [simply using `a`](http://jsfiddle.net/e11zpt5r/12/) if you want any links within your element.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thank you  for ur help

Comment: Doing an alert in a mouse over/enter/leave type event is really going to mess up the mouse event debugging and make it hard to discover issues.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are simply looking for the values of your `<a>` items inside your elements with the class `.previewCard-content`. You simply can add an event handler for them using `.on()` since they are loaded dynamically. The code below will print any text within `<a>` items inside your element to the console:

```
$(".previewCard-content").find("a").on("mouseover", function() {
   console.log($(this).text());
});
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/e11zpt5r/13/)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your [Fiddle Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/e11zpt5r/15/)

You already right with using variable $that in line 261 :

```
$that.hide().closest('p').next(".previewCard-content").slideDown("slow");
```

But you also need to do the same for $(this) in line 264 :

```
var LinkVal = $that.closest('div.previewCard-b').find('.previewCardPageLink').text();
```

I suppose this is just a little thing you forget. Because I can see you are on the right side with assigning $(this) to variable $that in line 257 :

```
var $that = $(this);
```

Since $(this) in there refers to the 'mouseover' element, while $(this) in 264 refers to setTimeout function.

Comment: I actually already pointed that out in the comments, but it seems that the OP selector isn't getting what they are expecting.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek well, I just stick with his requirement "trying to get the value of the text on which the user has moused over", as my updated Fiddle Demo do exactly that.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek There's a possibility that he doesn't get your first comment "What about using $that rather than this". I mean there're so many 'this' in his code, maybe he tried it in another line, and just forget to do it in that specific line. So, when he said "Just tried "that" didnt return anything" I doubt he really did exactly what you meant in the first place.